# Where are the developer options in Android 2.3.x?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings

I have Samsung Galaxy Exhibit 4G SGH-T679 running Android 2.3.6. I do not see the developer tools anywhere in the Settings menu.

Is there something special needed to get it to show up?

Comment: Haven't found anything at
developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: I thought "Developer options" were only hidden in Jelly Bean?

Comment: As w3d indicates, they were hidden with later versions. To reveal them there, you need to go to *Settings->About Phone*, and tap the "build version" 7 times fast (i.e. like double-tap speed). It usually displays a message then with some congratulations. You might test that on your device, though it should not have been hidden before JB.

Comment: It's under Applications/Development

Answer (score 45):

It has only been hidden since Android 4.2.

Back in Android 2.3, you just need to go to **Settings - Applications - Development**.